# Dynamic DNS slow to load the first time

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, self-hosting

I've set up a simple webpage running off my home server and I'm having trouble getting it to load at a reasonable speed the first time round.

The server is running the DuckDNS client and I'm using a CName record on the domain to redirect to the .duckdns.com subdomain.

The server runs XAMPP (apache) and the page is a simple html file with a bit of CSS. The trouble is, locally the page loads instantly, but if I use the actual .com domain of the site, it takes a few seconds to open the page. Once it's been loaded, it refreshes super quick, but I don't know if this is due to browser caching or something else.

Also I've redirected the domain to a directory of the duckdns site, as in example.duckdns.com/example, will this make any difference?

Comment: Some things do not make sense here. CNAME records can _only_ redirect a domain to another domain – they do not know anything about HTTP paths and cannot redirect to a subdirectory. (On the other hand, some domain registrars do provide HTTP redirects, but those are not CNAMEs...)

Comment: Your DNS is broken. If you provide the domain name we can look at it and provide some insights.

Comment: Open the network developer tool in your web browser (Ctrl-Shift-E on Firefox Windows) and load the page.  The timings tab shows you how much time was spent on DNS lookup and other tasks.